# Excel function reference specific cell and all cells below

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a function in excel that references a range from specific cell in a column, in this example A22 or B22 to the last cell in that column.  Something like this:

=MAX(IF('Sheet1'!$A$22:$A$LAST="YES",'Sheet1'!$B$22:$B$LAST))

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: how about some sample data with expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or........

```
=LOOKUP(1,0/(A:A="YES"),B:B)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the end reference with INDEX MATCH

```
=MAX(IF('Sheet1'!$A$22:INDEX('Sheet1'!$A:$A,MATCH(1E+99,'Sheet1'!$B:$B))="YES",'Sheet1'!$B$22:INDEX('Sheet1'!$B:$B,MATCH(1E+99,'Sheet1'!$B:$B))))
```

Remember to confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.